# Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm won't work

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, dijkstra

I have a graph with positive edge weights and positive node weights. The length of a path is defined as the sum of all the edge weights along the path, plus the maximum node weight encountered along the path.

I'd initially thought that a modified Dijkstra would work, but I found a test case where it would fail. How should I go about solving this problem? Are there any standard algorithms I should look at?

My modified Dijkstra is as follows: At each node I record the shortest path so far, and also the maximum node weight I've seen so far, and use that to calculate the length to neighboring nodes. Please see my comment for the details.

Here's a graph where Dijkstra fails:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFnMn.jpg
The numbers in green are the node labels. Everything in blue is weights (node and edge weights). Lets say I want to compute the shortest path between nodes 1 and 7 (labeled in green). The problem with Dijkstra is that the node 4 always records the path 1-8-9-4 since its shorter than path 1-2-3-4 (former length 9 vs latter length 13). But to reach node 7, path 1-8-9-4-5-6-7 is longer than 1-2-3-4-5-6-7.

Comment: What did you try and why did it fail? I am pretty sure a modified Dijkstra would work :-)

Comment: Fix the start node. For each of its neighbors, store a pair of numbers - (the shortest path to that neighbor,the maximum node weight encountered so far on the path to that node). Put them in a queue and pick the node having the shortest path. Continue. While adding a new node b connected to a visited node a, if weight of b < max node weight encountered on path to node a, the pair on b is (shortest path to a + edge weight ab, max node encountered till a). Else, the pair on b is (shortest path to a - max node till a + weight of node b + edge weight ab, weight of node b).

Comment: I think you solved "path with minimum total weight, plus keep track of the largest weighted edge on that path."  I think the problem is probably asking for "path with the minimum (total weight plus the largest weight)".  Simply tracking the largest weight won't solve that.

Comment: @DanielV By weight of a path I mean edge weights + max node weight encountered so far. So what you are calling total weight includes the max node weight encountered so far, not just the sum of edge weights. To clarify, the first number in the pair on each node is the (sum of edge weights + max node weight encountered so far, max node weight encountered so far)

Comment: Consider a graph G containing 2 vertexes s and t with the following properties:  (1) There are exactly 2 distinct paths from s to t (2)  The first path edge weights are {2, 1, 1, 1, 1} (3) The second path edge weights are {1, 1, 100} -- Most naive algorithms would give the s-t path as 201 rather than 8, as I think yours does if I interpret it as you intended.

Comment: I think you should show us some code, or at least some pseudo-code, to describe what you have done more formally. Ideally with examples of where your approach fails (and some where it works would be nice, too).

Comment: Would this question be more appropriate for cs.stackoverflow.com?

Answer (score 0):

If you can forgive one order larger polynomial time, then fairly easy algorithm:

```
ModifiedShortestPath(u, v, G) {
  X = StandardardShorestPath(u, v, G);
  E = heaviest edge in X
  F = all edges in G of weight >= E
  Y = ModifiedShortestPath(u, v, G - F); // recur here on G without the F edges
  return Min(X, Y);
}
```

The runtime of this is |E| times more than your standard shortest path.

Answer (score 0):

Your graph is not that clear to begin with (too many values in blue of unclear role), which makes answers even more difficult. A much better question, a simpler graph and some straight answers [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22625922/does-dijkstras-algorithm-give-shortest-path-always).

What made it clear for me, and allowed me to correct my implementation and get the correct results, was that at the end of each repetition in the loop, when it was time to pick the next node/vertex, whose unvisited neighbours I should examine, I had to pick from the whole pool of unvisited vertices, not just from the unvisited neighbours of the currently examined node. I was under the false impression that once you pick a path at a crossroad, because the greedy nature of the algorithm takes you there, you can only follow it to the end, unvisited after unvisited node. No. You pick the next **globally unvisited** node each time based on the smallest tentative value, regardless of its position in the graph or whether it is connected to the current node.

I Hope that clears the confussion that others like me have experienced and has led them here.