# Does Dijkstra's algorithm give shortest path always?

Tags: graph, dijkstra

I am learning Dijkstra's algorithm and had a basic query. I have a graph that looks as follows..(non-negative nodes):

A---2-----B------16------D-----3-------F
*                                      *
*                                      *
3                                      4
*                                      *
C----------2---------------------------E

Not clear from above graph display, but AC has a distance of 3 and EF has a distance of 4.

I am interested in finding shortest path between A and F.

Consider destination node F. When we consider its nearest node, we get D (DF has weight 3 and EF 4). However, when we follow that path, we get the shortest path as: A,B,D,F (total distance: 19).

A quick observation tells us that the shortest path is actually A,C,E,F (distance: 9). However, since in the 1st step, E was more distant than D, we followed D.

Am I missing something here? Dijkstra's algorithm is clearly not showing the right result here.

Comment: Yes you are missing something, the algorithm always picks the node with the smallest cumulative distance as the next node to explore. We won't mark the the destination node as visited until it's the smallest un-visited distance.

Answer (score 5):

Yes Dijkstra's always gives shortest path when the edge costs are all positive. However, it can fail when there are negative edge costs.

Comment: Negative edge costs invalidate all shortest-path algorithms on non-tree graphs (with negative cycles). You could take a negative edge over and over again to get an infinitely short path.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are missing something. Have a look at step 4 below.

1. The first step would be to mark D with tentative distance 3 and E with tentative distance 4.
2. The next step would select D as it is the non visited node with the lowest tentative distance
3. Then you would mark all non-visited nodes from D with their distances (mark B with tentative distance 19 (3 + 16))
4. Then select the next non-visited node with the lowest tentative distance. This would select E (4)
5. Mark all of E's nodes with their tentative distance. C gets marked as 6 (4+2).
6. Then select the next non-visited node with the lowest tentative distance. This would select C (6)
7. Mark all of C's nodes with their tentative distance. A gets marked as 9 (6+3).

Stop as you have reach A with a distance of 9.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm works just fine with your graph.  It must be a bug in your implementation.

```
Visit A
-Set B distance = 0 + 2 = 2, previous = A
-Set C distance = 0 + 3 = 3, previous = A
Visit B
-Set D distance = 2 + 16 = 18, previous = B
Visit C
-Set E distance = 3 + 2 = 5, previous = C
Visit E
-Set F distance = 5 + 4 = 9, previous = E
Visit F
-Set D distance = 9 + 3 = 12, previous = F // you can early-out here if you want
Visit D
-Alternate distance to F: 18 + 3 = 21 (fail since current distance, 9, is smaller)

Shortest path = F.previous = E, E.previous = C, C.previous = A
= A, C, E, F
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if you really understand the algorithm. Take a look at this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XB4MIexjvY0

Then implement it starting from vertex A.

Dijkstras Algorithm finds the shortest path from any given node to all other nodes, only if the edges are non-negative.